# Why is the domain of a lagrangian functional, of the form $\Omega\times\mathbb{R}^N\times\mathbb{R}^M$ instead of just $\Omega$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Here,

> [image: The Text]

I see no reason not to say $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ instead of $f:\Omega\times\mathbb{R}^N\times\mathbb{R}^M\to \mathbb{R}$.

(Since $u(x)$ and $Du(x)$ are themselves functions of $x$, so should be $f$.)

where am I going wrong?

Comment: It seems to me that there is a function $g:\Omega \to \Omega \times \mathbb R^N\times \mathbb R^M$, given by $g(x)=(x,u(x),Du(x))$, and then this $g$ gets composed with $f$. What you are calling $f$ is $f\circ g$.

Comment: @Moisés, then than means every $Du(x) \in \mathbb{R}^M$. But why?

Comment: I wouldn't trust the dimensions. Like it says on these notes at the beginning of chapter 4, the domain of $f$ is $\Omega\times \mathbb R^M \times \mathbb R^{N\times M}$. Like it says here, $u$ takes values in $\mathbb R^M$, not $\mathbb R^N$, and its differential is an $N\times M$ matrix.

Comment: @Moisés, with this modification, everything fits well together. I agree. This seems to be the solution. We have a typo here.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ becomes a function of $x$ only when you substitute $u(x)$ and $Du(x)$ into it. Consider a simple example where $\Omega=\mathbb R$ and $N=M=1$. Then $u$ is just a real-valued function, as well as its derivative $Du=u'$. We can define $f: \mathbb R\times\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ as e.g.

$$f(x,a,b) = x^2+2a - \exp(b)$$

This is a function of $3$ variables. When we substitute $f(x, u(x), u'(x))$, we get

$$f(x, u(x), u'(x)) = x^2+2u(x)-\exp(u'(x))$$

which becomes a function of $1$ variable. What matters is that the calculus of variations is concerned with the dependence of $f$ on $a$ and $b$ separately from dependence on $x$.